# ValueError: Socket has not been accepted, so cannot send over it

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, django-channels

I am working on a django chatting application using the websocket technology (Django-channels)
The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 101, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 116, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 50, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 173, in websocket_connect
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\anime_chat_app\common_anime_chat\consumers.py", line 166, in connect
    await self.send_message_to_client(message)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\anime_chat_app\common_anime_chat\consumers.py", line 179, in send_message_to_client
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 209, in send
    await super().send({"type": "websocket.send", "text": text_data})
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 81, in send
    await self.base_send(message)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 240, in handle_reply
    protocol.handle_reply(message)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\anime_chat\venvPath\lib\site-packages\daphne\ws_protocol.py", line 193, in handle_reply
    raise ValueError("Socket has not been accepted, so cannot send over it")
ValueError: Socket has not been accepted, so cannot send over it
```

The following is consumers.py (backend logic for the websocket):

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import ChatRoom, Message, Profile
from asyncer import asyncify

@sync_to_async
def save_message_to_database(chatroom_name, username, message):
    try:
        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(name=chatroom_name)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        new_message = Message.objects.create(chat_room=chatroom, sender=user_profile, content=message)
        print("Message saved to DB:", new_message)

    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"Chatroom with name '{chatroom_name}' does not exist.")
    
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"User profile with username '{username}' does not exist.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while saving the message: {e}")
@sync_to_async
def get_chatroom_by_name(name):
    try:
        return ChatRoom.objects.get(name=name)
    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        return None
@sync_to_async
def get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom):
    return list(Message.objects.filter(chat_room=chatroom).order_by('timestamp'))

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        print("Before getting chatroom")
        chatroom = await get_chatroom_by_name(self.room_name)
       
        print("chatroom:",chatroom)
    
        print("Chatroom:",chatroom)
        messages = await get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom.id)
        for message in messages:
            print("SENDING MESSAGE TO FUNCTION")
            await self.send_message_to_client(message)
        

        await self.accept()


    async def send_message_to_client(self, message):
        user_id = await sync_to_async(lambda: message.sender.user_id)()
        user = await sync_to_async(lambda: User.objects.get(id=user_id))()
        print("SENDING MESSAGES TO THE FRONTEND")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message.content,
            'username': user.username,
            'user_pfp': message.sender.profile_picture.url,
            'room_name': self.room_name,
        }))
    
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = text_data_json['username']
        user_pfp = text_data_json['user_pfp']
        room_name = text_data_json['room_name']

        await save_message_to_database(chatroom_name=room_name, username=username, message=message)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username,
                'user_pfp': user_pfp,
                'room_name': room_name,
                'tester_message': 'tester message in receive function'
            }
        )

    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        user_pfp = event['user_pfp']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'user_pfp': user_pfp,
            'tester_message': 'tester message in chatroom message'
        }))
```

I am basically creating a chatroom with a unique string as its unique name and passing information for various actions being done on my site such as opening the chatroom, sending messages etc. and using that information to add content to the frontend such as the user's username profile picture and the actual contents of their message.
The following is the frontend code (chatroom.html):

```
{% extends 'common_anime_chat/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'chatroom.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}
{% block content %}
<div class="chat-container">
  <div id="chat-messages"></div>
  <input type="text" id="input" size="80">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
</div>

{{ request.user.username|json_script:"user_username" }}
{{ request.user.profile.profile_picture.url|json_script:"user_pfp"}}
<script>
    const hardcodedProfilePictures = {
        'itsmyname': '/media/profile_pictures/profile1.png',
        'user123': '/media/profile_picturues/profile2.png',
        // Add more hardcoded profile pictures here for other usernames
    };

    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDOM = document.querySelector('#input');
        const message = messageInputDOM.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': userUsername,
            'user_pfp':userPfp,
            'room_name':roomName
        }));
        messageInputDOM.value = '';
    };

    const chatMessagesDOM = document.querySelector('#chat-messages');
    const userUsername = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent);
    // console.log(userUsername)
    const pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    const roomName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 2]; // Use -1 if the room name is in the last segment

    let userPfp = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_pfp').textContent);

    // Object to store profile pictures associated with usernames
    let profilePictures = {};

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' +
        window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' +
        roomName +
        '/'
    );
    chatSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
};

chatSocket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
};

chatSocket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
};

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    const messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    messageContainer.classList.add('chat-message');

    let profilePicture = document.createElement('img');
    profilePicture.src = data.user_pfp;
    profilePicture.alt = 'Profile Picture';
    profilePicture.classList.add('profile-picture');
    messageContainer.appendChild(profilePicture);

    const messageContent = document.createElement('span');
    messageContent.classList.add('message-content');

    const usernameSpan = document.createElement('span');
    usernameSpan.classList.add('username');
    usernameSpan.textContent = data.username;
    messageContent.appendChild(usernameSpan);

    const messageSpan = document.createElement('span');
    messageSpan.textContent = data.message;
    messageContent.appendChild(messageSpan);

    messageContainer.appendChild(messageContent);

    chatMessagesDOM.appendChild(messageContainer);
};

    // Fetch and load profile pictures for each user
    fetch('/api/get_user_profile_pictures/') // Change this URL to the endpoint that provides profile picture URLs for all users
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            profilePictures = data;
            console.log(profilePictures)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(profilePictures)
            console.error('Error loading profile pictures:', error);
        });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

The error is most likely being caused by the backend code but after some research online, I was not able to troubleshoot the issue so please help me out!